# PyMC Install error on Windows

Tags: python, fortran, gfortran, pymc

I am having a very difficult time installing pymc on windows.  I do

```
easy_install pymc
```

But it gives the error

```
error: Setup script exited with error: extension 'pymc.flib' has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

However, I installed the gFortran compiler within MinGW.  Do I have to change the environment variables or something?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure that you do in fact have the Fortran compiler installed with MinGW. If you open up **MinGW Installation Manager** (in `C:\MinGW\libexec\mingw-get\guimain.exe`) you will see a list of packages. If `mingw32-gcc-fortran` is unchecked, check it and click `Installation` **>** `Apply Changes`.

Secondly, check your **PATH** to make sure that `C:\MinGW\bin` is there and that there are not other versions of MinGW in the path (like a 64 bit version).

Lastly, if you are using 32-bit Python then your MinGW should be 32-bit, if 64-bit Python then use 64-bit MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the issue. You should probably add `C:\MinGW\bin` to your PATH.